# simple button effect will not work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a simple button animation but it will not work for some reason. I took the code from my brackets editor and put it in a codepen and it worked fine, but it will not work within the brackets editor.The new button works fine, but the other two will not. Any ideas?

```css
.btn-style {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #5C5C5C;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.btn-new {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.btn-roll {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 370px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.btn-hold {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 415px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

button:hover {
  color: black;
}

.btn-new:active {
  top: 32px;
}

.btn-roll:active {
  top: 372px;
}

.btn-hold:active {
  top: 417px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-new btn-style">New Game</button>

<button type="button" class="btn-roll btn-style">Roll Dice</button>

<button type="button" class="btn-hold btn-style">Hold</button>
```

Comment: can you be more specific about the issue you are facing?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what's wrong with the animation, because your code is correct. Is there any other stylesheet or script that could interfere with the animation?

However, here's some advice that *might* solve the problem: Don't use absolute positioning where possible.

Here, instead of changing the `top` property, you can change the `margin` to move the buttons down by 2 pixels:

```
.btn-new:active, .btn-roll:active, .btn-hold:active {
    margin: 2px 0 -2px 0;
}
```

And here's the full example:

```css
.btn-style {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #5C5C5C;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.btn-new {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.btn-roll {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 370px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.btn-hold {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 415px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

button:hover {
  color: black;
}

.btn-new:active, .btn-roll:active, .btn-hold:active {
  margin: 2px 0 -2px 0;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-new btn-style">New Game</button>

<button type="button" class="btn-roll btn-style">Roll Dice</button>

<button type="button" class="btn-hold btn-style">Hold</button>
```